# Proxy all api-calls of angular application

Tags: angular, proxy

I have an Angular application, which uses a set of APIs under

- https_//example.com/api/v1
- https_//someexample.org/api/v2
- https_//anexample.net/api/v3

I have a http-proxy under `localhost:8005`

Is it possible, to configure the Angular application,
to proxy all api-calls via `localhost:8005` ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: I looked at this and tried this.
But there is no possibility, to set the domain, traffic to which I want to proxify. 
Or do I miss something?